# Can't access site proxied by traefik from docker container

Tags: docker, traefik

I am able to access the sites from the serving machine, if I use the port number; for example http://localhost:8080 but if I try from outside my lan with url it won't work.
I have a frontend rule for traefik that works, but it don't work for the other containers.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --api --docker --logLevel=DEBUG
    hostname: mysite.ddns.net
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
      - bridge
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
      - 443:443
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - "/docker/traefikcompose/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
      - /docker/traefikcompose:/etc/traefik:rw
    container_name: traefik
networks:
  web:
    external: true
  bridge:
    external: false
```

traefik.toml:

```
traefikLogsFile = "log/traefik.log"
accessLogsFile = "log/access.log"
ProvidersThrottleDuration = "5s"
MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 200

debug = true
logLevel = "ERROR"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
[entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[api]
#dashboard = true
#entryPoint = "dashboard"
address= ":8080"

[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  #endpoint = "//var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  domain = "mysite.ddns.net"
  watch = true
  exposedbydefault = true

[acme]
  email = "mymail@gmail.com"
  #caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
  storage = "acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  acmeLogging = true
  onDemand = true
  OnHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "mysite.ddns.net"
```

I have a Ghost-Blog and Home-assistant in separate ymls:

Ghost Blog Docker-Compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  ghost:
    image: ghost
    container_name: ghost
    hostname: mysite.ddns.net
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
      - bridge
    ports:
      - 2368:2368
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=ghost"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /blog, ${DOMAINNAME}"
      - "traefik.port=2368"
    volumes:
     - "/docker/ghost/blog:/var/lib/ghost/content"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - url=http://mysite.ddns.net

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  bridge:
    external: false
```

Home Assistent Docker Compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  home-assistant:
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant
    container_name: home-assistant
    hostname: mysite.ddns.net
    privileged: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
      - bridge
    ports:
      - 8123:8123
      - 8943:8943
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=home-assistant"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /hass"
      - "traefik.port=8123"
      #- "traefik.basic.protocol=http"
    volumes:
      - "/docker/home-assistant/config:/config"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    devices:
      - "/dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  bridge:
    external: false
```

DOMAINNAME is defined and works in a .env file. I have opened ports 80, 443, 2368, 8123, 8080 in firewall and router.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need the `ports:` configuration in the docker-compose.yml (except for traeffic) because traeffic will already serve them from as you configured with the labels.


Furthermore, can you clearify which URL you are trying to reach from outside?
From my side of view you can reach https://<DOMAINNAME>?

Comment: Error connection refused on https and 404 on http

Comment: Ok, lets try again. I think I wasn't clear in what I was writing. Can you reach https://example.com:443/hass or https://example.com:443/blog or did you tried on https://example.com:8943 ?

Comment: Sorry, I can now access http://example.com/traefik and also /blog and /hass from outside my lan but all .js will not load on /blog and /hass so they don’t render correctly. Https seems not to work anywhere I try

Comment: Ok, thats part of a different problem. As you are serving your files from a subpath of your domain you have to tell your websites that they are located in this subpath (otherwise they are running into 404s as they try to resolve relative to you root). For Ghost this is fairly simple. just set your `url` Variable in the docker Compose to `http://example.com/blog`. The Home automation service is not capable of beeing hosted in a subpath (but there is a [Feature Request](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/configurable-webroot/516/32) to enable it.). As a workaround just serve it from you root.

Comment: You might ask a new question regarding https as this can be a fairly complex topic. You should also close all ports not needed for traefik (2365 and 8123).

Comment: Thanks, I changed /hass to point at root works fine and I closed the ports, /traefik also works fine from outside. However /blog I got error "Cannot GET /"

Comment: Do you have changed the url in your Ghost Blog Docker Compose? `- url=http://mysite.ddns.net` to `- url=http://mysite.ddns.net/blog`

Comment: Yes, makes no different. I changed to another url for the moment so it will work :)


The https not working I think is because of traefik.toml and possible acme.json not getting mounted. I run docker toolbox on W7 and have mounted dirs in VirtualBox but no luck :(